# Is there a faster way to check if an item in a list if it is greater than, less than, equal to a certain number?

Tags: java

Is there a faster way to check if an item in a list is greater than, less than, equal to a certain number?

Or you just have to loop through it? Im just curious if there are pre-built functions for this.

Example:

List contains 5, 5, 10, 15, 15, 20.

I want to check if how many items are actually >= 5. So the answer is 6. If I want to check >= 15, the answer would be 3.

Comment: Do you mean if there exists an item in a list that is greater than, less than or equal to a certain number?

Comment: yes. sorry if there was a confusion.

Comment: The problem statement isn't clear enough to be able to figure out a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by faster - coding time? Why not write your own method?

Comment: That is why i am asking a question if there is such method that currently exists within the Collection. If not then yes I will write my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
step 1 : sort the list
step 2 : find the index for desired element
step 3 : print length-index
```

Comment: Well i might go with this one. Based on user000001 there is no such method that exists.

Comment: Traversing the whole list has a O(n) order of complexity. Sorting it may have a O(n * log(n)) order of complexity. So I would not suggest you sort it in the hope it would improve performances.

Comment: What if I do list.indexOf(certain number) then any number from that index to the last is >= certain number (assuming that number really exists in the list)? is it still O(n)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any such methods [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), so I would say **NO**. You have to iterate through the List. If it is sorted, you can do binary search for faster results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop to check the condition for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to sort? If you are dealing with arrays you can use `Arrays.sort()` else if you are dealing with collections you can use `Collections.sort()`

Comment: no. I just want to check if say how many entries in a list is >= 5.

Comment: ooh I think you really need to traverse and count then.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no pre-built function afaik. If your list items are not order critical(i.e. you are not making any priority list or LIFO/FIFO), you can improve the searching through sorting list before finding the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list and then you'll have to compare only its first and the last elements with the number.

Answer (score 0):

> That is why I am asking a question if there is such method that currently exists within the Collection.

There is no such method in the standard collection APIs.

Write a loop.  It should be quicker code and test a 5 line method to do this than scouring the internet for a 3rd party library.  And your code will most likely be faster ... and certainly no slower.

Just do it.  (I'd write the code for you myself, but it sounds like you need the practice ...)